# How to do a subtraction inside a list?

Tags: python, list, indexing, subtraction

I have 3 lists and 1 value:

```
my_value = 500

minimal_values = ['0,32', '0,35', '0,45']
maximal_values = ['0,78', '0,85', '0,72']

my_list = [
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '190,00', '0,15'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'], 
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
    ['Morocco', 'Meat', '187,99', '0,101'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,76', '0,10'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '190,16', '0,20'], 
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
    ['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,20', '0,11'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '190,10', '0,31'], 
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72'],
    ['Italy', 'Meat', '187,36', '0,80']]
```

Right now I'am filtering my code and trying to do a subtstraction of `my_value` - `index [2]` in `results`. Filtering is going well, its just the substraction that doesnt work in my output yet. Below is the code:

```
# Convert values to float.
minimal_values = [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in minimal_values]
maximal_values = [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in maximal_values]

# Collect all unique countries in a list.
countries = list(set(country[0] for country in my_list))

results = []
for l in my_list:
    i = countries.index(l[0])
    if minimal_values[i] <= float(l[-1].replace(',', '.')) <= maximal_values[i]:
        new_index_2 = my_value - float(l[-2].replace(',', '.'))  #<--- this is where I do the substraction
        results.append(l)
print(results)
```

This is the output I get:

```
[['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,90', '0,32'],
['Morocco', 'Meat', '189,38', '0,44'],
['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,94', '0,60'],
['Morocco', 'Meat', '188,49', '0,78'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '189,56', '0,35'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '189,01', '0,40'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '188,13', '0,75'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '187,95', '0,85'],
['Italy', 'Meat', '189,32', '0,45'],
['Italy', 'Meat', '188,61', '0,67'],
['Italy', 'Meat', '188,01', '0,72']]
```

As you can see, its not substracting `500` - `index [2]`....

This is the output I want:

```
[['Morocco', 'Meat', '310,10', '0,32'],
['Morocco', 'Meat', '310,62', '0,44'],
['Morocco', 'Meat', '311,06', '0,60'],
['Morocco', 'Meat', '311,51', '0,78'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '310,44', '0,35'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '310,99', '0,40'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '311,87', '0,75'],
['Spain', 'Meat', '312,05', '0,85'],
['Italy', 'Meat', '310,68', '0,45'],
['Italy', 'Meat', '311,39', '0,67'],
['Italy', 'Meat', '311,99', '0,72']]
```

Comment: Your life would be *much* easier if you converted the "numbers" in your lists into actual numbers, and only converted back to strings (with the appropriate formatting of thousands and decimal separators) when you display them.

Comment: @Nick I do convert them to actual numbers when I do a filter or a calculation.

Comment: It's a straight forward list comprehension `[ r[0:2] + [my_value - to_float(r[2])] + [r[3]] for r in my_list ]`.  to_float left as exercise for reader.

Comment: I prefer the answer below as that a simple one. But thank you :)

Comment: No worries.  Next time, please try to minimize your example.  It's slow to reverse engineer your existing code, and integrating a small bit into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you are missing is updating the list after subtraction.

Just add this line to your code after getting **new_index_2**.

```
new_index_2 = my_value - float(l[-2].replace(',', '.'))
l[-2] = new_index_2  #update the value back to list
results.append(l)
```

you can still improve the readability by giving the meaning full names to variables.

Comment: I think you end up with a float in l[-2] but he wanted a string.

Answer (score 1):

```py
results = []
for l in my_list:
    i = countries.index(l[0])
    if minimal_values[i] <= float(l[-1].replace(',', '.')) <= maximal_values[i]:
        new_index_2 = my_value - float(l[-2].replace(',', '.'))  #<--- this is where I do the substraction
        new_index_2 = str(new_index_2).replace('.', ',') # to keep your style
        l[2] = new_index_2 ### !!! Add this line
        results.append(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

It took some digging but this might be the cleanest way to deal with the float conversions:

```
 import locale
 locale._override_localeconv['decimal_point'] = ','
 locale.atof('1,2')
 1.2
 locale.str(1.2)
 '1,2'
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before you have to update the list once you have done the subtraction, but this still won't give you the desired output as it would be off by some decimals.

You should also change the line

`if minimal_values[i] <= float(l[-1].replace(',', '.')) <= maximal_values[i]:`

to

`if minimal_values[i] <= float(l[-1].replace(',', '.')) and float(l[-1].replace(',', '.')) <= maximal_values[i]:`

And with this two modifications the output is exactly the one you expected